# Google Script - Unzipping a Mimetype application/x-zip

Tags: google-apps-script

I regularly download a .zip file (that isn't created by me) that is Mimetype "application/x-zip" which isn't being processed by Utilities.unzip(file) with the following errors. I am hoping someone is able to help me parse this file.

Thanks.

```js
var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newestFileId);  
   //Successfully gets the file as verified by other processes
var thisBlob = thisFile.getBlob();
var createMe = thisFolder.createFile("workingb.zip", thisBlob, "application/zip");  
   //Creates a 4-byte file with the text "Blob"
var createMe = thisFolder.createFile("workingf.zip", thisFile, "application/zip");  
   //Creates an 11-byte file with the text the same as the filename.ext
Logger.log(thisFile.getMimeType());  
   // "application/x-zip"
 var test1 = thisFile.getAs("application/zip");  
   //Exception: Converting from application/x-zip to application/zip is not supported
var thisUnzip = Utilities.unzip(test1); 
   //Exception: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are 2 patterns for your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

If the extension of filename is `.zip`, how about this modification?

Modified script:

```
var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newestFileId);
var thisBlob = thisFile.getBlob();
var convertedBlob = thisBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension();
var thisUnzip = Utilities.unzip(convertedBlob);
```

#### Pattern 2:

If the filename has no extension or the extension is the value except for `.zip`, how about this modification?

Modified script:

```
var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newestFileId);  
var thisBlob = thisFile.getBlob();
var convertedBlob = thisBlob.setContentType("application/zip");
var thisUnzip = Utilities.unzip(convertedBlob);
```

#### References:

- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentTypeFromExtension())
- [setContentType(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)

If these were not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Joblio I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.